# Как работает часть программы?

Tags: c++

```
while (!(cin >> number) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
{
    cin.clear();
    while (cin.get() != '\n')
            ;
    cout << "Ошибка ввода. Введите заново:`введите сюда код` " << endl;
}
```

Не могу понять как он работает, что делают cin.peek(), !(cin >> a), cin.clear(), cin.get()
Помогите разобраться.

С++

Comment: как вам помочь, если вы не пытаетесь изучать и пока не знаете что такое  cin.get()?

Comment: Вот сейчас и пытаюсь разобраться зачем они нужны

Comment: Вы  хотите изучать язык здесь, не открывая учебники? Я понимаю, когда не знают про   cin.peek(), но как можно не знать про  cin.get()?

Comment: Я прочитал, но не понял что именно она делает и хотел разобрать на примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- cin.peek() _ возвращает целочисленное представление следующего
  символа в буфере потока, не прочитав его
- (cin >> a) при вводе значения `a`, если все нормально, то выражение
  вернет  true, соответственно `!(cin >> a)`  вернет  `false` (неудачу)
- `cin.clear()` очистит все биты и установит бит по умолчанию
  (std::ios_base::goodbit), таким образом приведя поток в рабочее
  состояние.
- cin.get() считывает один символ, но нигде не хранит

Таким образом имеем следующее:

```
while (!(cin >> number) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
```

Пока попытка вводить с консоли значение  `number` завершилась неудачей, или символ, следующий за последным прочитанным, не является '\n'(строка не закончилась). (Чушь какая то написана)
    {

```
    cin.clear();
```

очищаем `cin`,  приводим его в рабочее состояние  (установится состояние good)

```
    while (cin.get() != '\n');
```

Читаем всю оставшуюся строку посимвольно(т.е. пока не встретим  '\n')

```
    cout << "Ошибка ввода. Введите заново:`введите сюда код` " << endl;
}
```

выводим на консоль сообщение об ошибке.

Вообшем  написано плохо(ради чего вся остальная строка пропускается, непонятно), такой код нужно писать как: вводим число, если это не число или cin сломался по другой причине,  поток приводим в рабочее состояние и игнорируем всю строку.

Comment: Надеюсь стало понятнее

Comment: я бы добавил что есть такая вещь, как `cin.ignore` и у неё есть 2 параметр - символ до которого пропускать.

Comment: @pavel ,  последнее предложение читайте.  Как это сделать, вопрос уже другой

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, *`"Чушь какая то написана"`* -- код `while (!(cin >> number) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))` проверяет формат ввода по одному числу на строку (причем после числа должен быть сразу `\n`)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, `!(cin >> number)` ловит ошибки только вида `q234` вместо `1234`, а весь этот код ловит также ошибки типа `123r` вместо `1234`, которые без него обнаруживаются **только** при вводе следующего числа (в как бы правильное число 123 на самом деле-то ошибка).

Answer (score 1):

`cin` - это входной поток.
`cout` - это выходной поток.
`cerr` - это поток вывода сообщений об ошибках.

Для работы с этими операторами есть специальные поразрядные сдвиги:
`>>` - прочитать из входного потока.
`<<` - записать в выходной поток

От суда вывод, что `cin` - это ввод, из данного потока - читается последовательность символов до пробела и после помещается в идентификатор (переменную).

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

Допустим, если взять строку состоящую из 2 и более слов, разделенными: пробелом, переводом строки, табуляцией, к примеру `Тут Текст`:

```
char s[10];
cin >> s;
cout << s << endl;
```

Вернет `Тут`.
Чтобы нам получить всю строку, нужно использовать манипулятор `getline`.

```
char s[10];
cin.getline(s, 10);
cout << s << endl;
```

Вернет `Тут Текст`.

Так-же поддерживается мульти-ввод:

```
cin >> var1 >> var2 >>...>> varN;
```